# How to use "this" keyword as parameter?

Tags: java

Why do I get an error when I try to execute this? it says required to arguments, found int int int.

```
public class testt
{   int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    public testt (){
        this(0,0,0);
    }
}
```

also, what does it mean to have "this" as an parameter?
eg

```
Object object = new Object (this);
```

Comment: *"Why do I get an error when I try to execute this?"* - `testt` has no constructor matching `testt(int, int, int)`.  *"also, what does it mean to have "this" as an parameter?*" - It means you're passing a reference of the current instance of an object to the other object

Comment: Check [Using the this Keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Comment: I get a feeling the answers provided here might not suit OP.  I'd recommend picking up an Introductory Java text. Maybe even https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: "Why do I get an error when I try to execute this?"  You don't.  You get an error when you try to *compile* it, and if the error message doesn't give you at least a general idea of what the problem is then you need a better compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using this as a constructor call, e.g.

```
this(0,0,0);
```

would require a constructor with 3 integer arguments:

```
public class testt
{   
 int a;
 int b;
 int c;
 public testt (){
    this(0,0,0);
 }
 public testt(int a, int b, int c) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c;
 }
}
```

If you use `this` as a parameter, you are passing this instance of the object into a method.